# Error occurred in defining array index although index is found when I print the array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create an array inside another one using (KEY) ,and when I try to print the mother array ,the child array appears inside it ,but compiler gives me an error , Here is my code

```
$reps_conts["filters"] = array();
                foreach($data as $key => $div){
                    if($div == "compls"){
                       $reps_conts["filters"]["scompls"] = "scompls";
                    }
                    if($div == "obsts"){
                       $reps_conts["filters"]["sobsts"] = "sobsts";
                    }
                    if($div == "notes"){
                      $reps_conts["filters"]["snotes"] = "snotes";
                    }
                }
                print_r($reps_conts);
                $this->load->view('mitronik/aggregation-result' ,array('data' => $reps_conts));
```

and Here is the output when I print the array ($reps_conts)

> Array ( [235] => Array ( [HEAD] => 114705 [COMPL] => إنجازات يونيو
>   2019 . وزارة الصحة [OBST] => [NOTE] => [APPROVED] => 1 [head_name] =>
>   حسن علي عيد العباسي ) [approvals] => Array ( [235] => 1 [1332] => 0
>   [1128] => 0 ) [filters] => Array ( [scompls] => scompls ) ) A PHP
>   Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: filters
>
> Filename: mitronik/aggregation-result.php
>
> Line Number: 18

Backtrace:

> File:
>   /var/www/html/itachievements/application/views/mitronik/aggregation-result.php
>   Line: 18 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /var/www/html/itachievements/application/controllers/Welcome.php
>   Line: 353 Function: view
>
> File: /var/www/html/itachievements/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: Can you add more code? It says error on line 18, but not visible from your code.

Comment: Please add your "aggregation-result.php" file code. it show error in this file at line no 18

Comment: Yes ,I checked out the file "aggregation-result.php" there is a foreach clause that checks an array an must exclude some keys of the array .I excluded that keys and it works fine now ,Thank you so much Amarat